# An urn contains ten balls numbered 1 to 10. Using the Law of total probability, What is the probability that the 3rd ball drawn is numbered 3

Tags: probability

I know the answer to this question is 1/10 because we know nothing about the previous two balls drawn before we draw the third ball, however Im unsure how to prove it using the law of total probability. I am able to prove it if it was the second ball drawn ie:

**P**(Draw2 is Ball3) = **P**(Draw2 is Ball3 | Draw1 is Ball3)**P**(Draw1 is Ball3) + **P**(Draw2 is Ball3|Draw1 not Ball3)**P**(Draw1 not Ball3)

The numbers end up being:

P(Draw2 is Ball3) = 0*(1/10) + 1/9*(9/10) = 1/10

Im not quite sure how to show it for the third draw using the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

If we call the event "ball $i$ is $3$" $E_i(3)$, then the probability we want is

\begin{align*}
P(E_3(3)) &= P(E_3(3) \cap E_2(3)^c \cap E_1(3)^c) \\
 &= P(E_3(3) | E_2(3)^c \cap E_1(3)^c) \\
& \times P(E_2(3)^c | E_1(3)^c) \\
 & \times P(E_1(3)^c). \
\end{align*}

From here, it's not hard to calculate the individual conditional probabilities -- for instance, $P(E_2(3)^c | E_1(3)^c) = 8/9$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you that makes so much sense! I didn't think of using complements to do this but it works

Answer (score 0):

$R$ is the event that ball 3 drawn on either of the first two draws.

$S$ is the event that ball 3 drawn on the 3rd draw.

Then,

$$p(S) = [p(S|R) \times p(R)] + [p(S|\neg R) \times p(\neg R)].$$

You have already used the Law of Total Probability to compute the probability that Ball 3 was drawn on the 2nd draw.  You can simply add that to the probability of Ball 3 being drawn on the 1st draw.  This gives you $p(R).$

Comment: This makes sense as well, the grouping of the events for ball 1 and 2 into one event R really help simplify this problem. Thank you!